# flutter padding to text in textfield

Tags: flutter, user-interface, uitextfield, height, textfield

I have given the textfield a custom height with a container around it. The icons are stlii in the middle  but the text is not in the center of the textfield. Do somebody know a way to fix this problem?

```
Container(
                          height: 45,
                          child: TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Colors.grey[100],
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  width: 0,
                                  style: BorderStyle.none,
                                ),
                              ),
                              hintText: 'Hint Text',
                            ),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For horizontally centered hint text**: The hint text aligns according to the `TextFormField`'s `textAlign`, so adding `textAlign: TextAlign.center` to the `TextFormField` will center the hint text horizontally.

**For vertically centered hint text**: Add a `contentPadding`, e.g., `contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2)` to the `TextField`.

```
Container(
          height: 45,
          child: TextFormField(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center, // this is new
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              filled: true,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2), // this is new
              fillColor: Colors.grey[100],
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  width: 0,
                  style: BorderStyle.none,
                ),
              ),
              hintText: 'Hint Text',
            ),
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```